# Sort a dictionary containing child dictionary, by using value of a key in the child dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Suppose that I have a dictionary containing dictionary like this example:

```
a_dict = {
  'abcd': {'name': 'John', 'height': 180},
  'asdf': {'name': 'Lex', 'height': 160},
  'csxf': {'name': 'Amber', 'height': 193},
}
```

How do I sort the dictionary using value of the key in child dictionary, i.e: value of the `'height'` key?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by a value of the dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary) As well as [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/613183/4518341)

Comment: No, I've been thru that and, those were not nested dictionary @wjandrea

Comment: It's the same idea though. Can't you see the resemblance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
dict(sorted(a_dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]["height"]))
```

Comment: `TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str` You just forgot `item[1]`

Comment: @wjandrea still produce error: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'

Comment: @ewin Oops, that was unclear. I meant `item[1]["height"]`

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks, it works! Now what was the indice [1] in item[1] refer to actually?

Comment: @ewin Think about it, what does `dict.items()` give you? What's the second element in each item?

Comment: @wjandrea Got it, thx. Im an idiot.